# Como usar fazer o use chamar outro namespace sem usar o include?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, include, namespace

Vejo a toda hora os programadores usando o comando "use" abaixo do comando "namespace" sem antes usar um include.

Um exemplo é a library Medoo:

```
namespace Medoo;

use PDO;
use Exception;
use PDOException;

class Raw {
    public $map;
    public $value;
}
```

Como isso funciona? Eu tento fazer o mesmo mas nunca dá certo.

Vejam o meu exemplo e me expliquem, por favor, o que há de errado:

Diretórios:

```
App
|
+--- MyspaceA
|       |
|       +--- MyclassA.php
|
+--- MyspaceB
|       |
|       +--- MyclassB.php
|
+--- index.php
```

MyclassA.php:

```
<?php namespace MyspaceA;

    class MyclassA {
        public static $myvarA = "Ola Mundo";
    }

?>
```

MyclassB.php:

```
<?php namespace MyspaceB;

    use MyspaceA\MyclassA;

    class MyclassB {
        public static $myvarB = "!!!!!";
    }

    $myvarC = MyclassA::$myvarA + MyclassB::$myvarB;

?>
```

index.php:

```
<?php 

include("MyspaceA/MyclassA.php");
include("MyspaceB/MyclassB.php");

echo($myvarC);

?>
```

O resultado que eu esperava:

```
Ola Mundo!!!!!
```

Mas dá erro!

O que está errado no meu código?

Comment: Dê uma olhada nos links do box amarelo acima da sua pergunta, as respostas ali devem esclarecer sua dúvida. Caso contrário, avise aqui.

Comment: Então, na verdade, eu já vi essas respostas, mas achei elas MUITO complicadas! Envolvem composer e explicações super teóricas de spl e tal. Eu queria algo bem simplesinho, bem feijão com arroz, fazer essas clases funcionarem com o menor código possível.

Comment: Você precisa implementar um autoloader (não se assuste que a função inicia com `spl_`).  A resposta do Guilherme na pergunta linkada mostra como. Outra coisa, sua `$myvarC` é global, no PHP namespaces não englobam variáveis.

Comment: Eu realmente não entendi... Eu sei como usar o autoload. O que eu não entendo e não funciona comigo é usar um comando USE abaixo do comando NAMESPACE.

Comment: Ok. Por favor edite a pergunta e explique o que está dando errado no seu exemplo. Aí posso reabrir a pergunta. Porque eu não entendi o que você não entendeu :). O `use` você precisa usar toda vez que tiver de usar classes que venham de outro namespace.

Comment: Bom... então talvez essa seja a pergunta certa: Que comandos eu preciso escrever no arquivo index.php para que o comando USE abaixo do NAMESPACE no aquivo MyclassB.php funcione? Possivelmente, terei q usar um comando __autoload  no index.php. E, em outras vezes, eu já usei o comando __autoload com sucesso. Mas eu não nunca consigo fazer o comando use carregar uma outra classe através do __autoload, então, tô escrevendo alguma coisa errada. Mas não sei o quê. <<< Será que essa edição serve?